# Dump output of macro to null

Tags: nsis

This mainly a curiosity question, but nevertheless. Imagine I have a macro with the declaration:

```
!define foo "!insertmacro foo"
!macro foo in1 in2 out1 out2 out3
    ; the code here
!macroend
```

with `inX` for inputs and `outX` for outputs. Now, I don't need all three outputs too often (e.g. one of them is an exit status returned by a winapi call), but still have to pass variables as placeholders to please the macro syntax:

```
${foo} $1 $2 $R1 $R2 $R3
```

Is there any syntax like

```
${foo} $1 $2 $R1 nul nul
```

to drop the unneeded output?

EDIT: Please also explain how to handle variable arguments for hybrids. SCCE:

```
OutFile sccce.exe

!define foo "!insertmacro foo"
!macro foo in1 out1 out2
    Push "${in1}"
    Call bar
    Pop "${out1}"
!macroend

Section
    ${foo} $0 $1 $2 ; compilable
    ${foo} $0 $1 "" ; not compilable
SectionEnd

Function bar
    Pop $0
    IntOp $0 $0 + 1
    Push $0
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any magic string you like to signal a unused macro parameter and then check for this in the macro implementation. The other alternative would be to create your own $null variable at the top of your script.

```
!macro Foo always maybe
IntOp ${always} 666 * 1337
!if "${maybe}" != ""
  IntOp ${maybe} 1234 * 1337
!endif
!macroend

!insertmacro Foo $0 ""
!insertmacro Foo $0 $1
```

*Edit:*

There is no `$optimize_me_away` variable and no way to `PopAndDiscard` so you have to find a way to throw away the result:

```
!macro foo_alt1 in1 out1 ; The disadvantage with this method is that the common case is "bloated"
Push "${in1}"
Call bar_alt1 ; Will store result in $0
!if "${out1}" == ""
Pop $0
!else if "${out1}" != $0
StrCpy ${out1} $0
Pop $0
!endif
!macroend

Function bar_alt1
Exch $0
IntOp $0 $0 + 1
FunctionEnd

!include LogicLib.nsh
!macro foo_alt2 in1 out1
Push "${in1}"
Call bar_alt2
!if "${out1}" == ""
!insertmacro _LOGICLIB_TEMP ; LogicLib has a internal varible we can use, or you can make your own
Pop $_LOGICLIB_TEMP 
!else
Pop ${out1}
!endif
!macroend

Function bar_alt2
Exch $0
IntOp $0 $0 + 1
Exch $0
FunctionEnd


Section
!macro test alt

StrCpy $0 PreserveMe
!insertmacro foo_alt${alt} 1337 $1
DetailPrint r0=$0,r1=$1

!insertmacro foo_alt${alt} 1337 $0
DetailPrint r0=$0

!insertmacro foo_alt${alt} 1337 ""
DetailPrint NoResult
!macroend

!insertmacro test 1
!insertmacro test 2

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Anders! Got it now.

Comment: I'm sorry to reopen it, Anders, but I forgot to ask also about hybrids - please consider my edits in question. Are no empty strings allowed in case of hybrids?

Comment: Pop'ing into $_LOGICLIB_TEMP is the best option AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you again for the explanation, Anders! You are a true guru of NSIS :-)